# How can I input two variable parameters using find exec?

Tags: find, exec

I am trying to use find exec like this

```
find . -name '*xlsx' -exec xlsx2csv-2.7 -i --skipemptycolumns
```

The problem is that xlsx2csv needs two parameters at the end, input file name and output file name.

I have a bunch of files 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx and so on that I want to convert to CSV and name 1.csv, 2.csv...

Basically I need to run the following commands

```
xlsx2csv-2.7 -i --skipemptycolumns 1.xlsx 1.csv

xlsx2csv-2.7 -i --skipemptycolumns 2.xlsx 2.csv
```

Can this be done using find exec? If not, are there other better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
find -name '*.xslx' -exec sh -c 'xlsx2csv-2.7 -i --skipemptycolumns {} `echo {} | sed 's/\.xlsx/\.csv/'`' \;
```